# Exception while calling updating data

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

this is my jsp file to edit data.

CustomerEdit.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">

<h3>Edit Customer Information</h3>

</div>
<form:form id="editForm" modelAttribute="user" action="editsave"
method="post">

 <table align="center">
<tr>
<td><form:label path="customerid"></form:label></td>
<td><form:hidden path="customerid" name="customerid" id="customerid" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="firstname">Firstname</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="lastname">Lastname</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="street">Street</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="street" name="street" id="street" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="city" name="city" id="city" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="province">Province</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="province" name="province" id="province" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="country">Country</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="country" name="country" id="country" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="birthday">Birthday</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="birthday" name="birthday" id="birthday" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="sin">SIN</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="sin" name="sin" id="sin" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="passport">Passport Number</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="passport" name="passport" id="passport" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="nationality">Nationality</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="nationality" name="nationality" id="nationality" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="email">Email Address</form:label></td>
<td><form:input path="email" name="email" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="loginid"></form:label></td>
<td><form:hidden path="loginid" name="loginid" id="loginid" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form:label path="password">Password</form:label></td>
<td><form:password path="password" name="password"
id="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><form:button id="submit" name="submit">Save</form:button></td>
</tr>
</table>
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller

```
@Controller
public class RegisterControl {​​​
 @Autowired
 UserDao dao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/editcust/{customerid}")
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable int customerid, Model m) {
   User cust = dao.getCustomerById(customerid);
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("CustomerEdit");
   mav.addObject("user", cust);
   return mav;
}

 public UserService userService;
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editsave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    System.out.println("HELLOOOOO!!!!!");
    dao.update(user);
    return "redirect:/homepage";
 }
}
```

I get My customerEdit form with data. but when I click on save to update my data I get Exception

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "editsave"]
```

I don't even get HELLOOOO printed on console.

PS: My Register form is working but getting error while updating data.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are sending some kind of User field which is declared as int equal to "editsave" (which is string).

You can just change all User fields to String and check (with debug) which field is making problems.

You should realy make sure that client isn't able to send non number type of that field, although it may be tricky because you can't add `type` attribute because the `spring:input` form tag doesnt support the type attribute and there is no such thing as `spring:number`. But you can use jquery to add the type="number" attribute to the parsed html. Something like this:

```
$(".selector").attr({
    "type" : "number",
});
```

**EDIT after new exception:**

you also need to add BindingResult to your controller method. In case you want to validate any field of User object you can set errors into it. If not, you can just copy my snippet

```
public UserService userService;
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editsave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("HELLOOOOO!!!!!");
    dao.update(user);
    return "redirect:/homepage";
 }
```

Comment: I changed every field to string.. so the earlier exception got solved but now I get another exception "with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute"

Comment: you need to add "BindingResult result" after @ModelAttribute bean in your controller method. Check my edited post

Comment: for this error "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute" it was silly mistake, while calling the controller I was just passing the API 'editsave' in my jsp instead I called using "projectname/editsave" and it worked. Thanks for suggesting change fields to string it lead me solve my error.